# seperate function with sep = "|" doesn't work

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this example *dataframe*, and want to separate on *"|"* explicitly:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("11|", "22|", "|33", "44|")) 

df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"), sep = "|")
```

Which gives below, **not** what I need:

```
#   A B
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3   |
# 4   4
# Warning message:
#   Too many values at 4 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I expected this output:

```
#    A  B
# 1 11   
# 2 22   
# 3    33
# 4 44
```

Comment: You'd need `sep = "\\|"`, because `|` has a meaning in regex. I'm still not sure the result is very useful, though.

Comment: Also, `separate` already does it by default, so you could just do `df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"))`

Comment: @alistaire Surprised it doesn't have `fixed = TRUE` option. Maybe post your comment an as answer?

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. Yes, this is working now. Great !!!

Answer (score 6):

Since `|` means "or" in regex, you need to escape it with `\\` if you mean it literally:

```r
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c("11|", "22|", "|33", "44|")) 

df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"), sep = "\\|")
#>    A  B
#> 1 11   
#> 2 22   
#> 3    33
#> 4 44
```

As David points out, though, that is included in the default for `sep`, `"[^[:alnum:]]+"`, which uses any non-alphanumeric characters as separators, so leaving out the parameter will do what you want. Adding `convert = TRUE` will convert the numbers into actual numbers, as well, so you can write:

```r
df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"), convert = TRUE)
#>    A  B
#> 1 11 NA
#> 2 22 NA
#> 3 NA 33
#> 4 44 NA
```

which is probably a more useful form.